# Having Troubles with text to hexadecimal program in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am fairly new to python programming, but I am attempting to make my own simple encryption program for a school project. I have finally gotten started after a lot of research, mainly about the syntax of different python commands. Anyway, one section of my code involves translating two lines of text (key, and msg) into hexadecimal in order to perform my simple encryption algorithm. Although everything seems correct, I sometimes get outputs with a capital L at the end of the hexadecimal string. (example below with code) Any advice would be helpful!

Assume msg = "hello world" and key = "/abc for example.

```
# define functions

def function_hex(string, length):
  variable = "0x00"
  for i in xrange(0, length):
    n = ord(string[i])
    variable = hex(256 * int(variable, 16) + n)      #line 24
  return variable

# transform input / key to hex

msg_hex = function_hex(msg, msg_length)              #line 29
print msg_hex

key_hex = function_hex(key, key_length)
print key_hex
```

output

```
message:  hello world
key:  /abc
encrypt or decrypt:  encrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 29, in <module>
  File "python", line 24, in function_hex
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: '0x68656c6c6f20776f72L'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam,
Can I suggest a better method?

```
# define functions
msg = "hello world"
key = "/abc"

def function_hex(s):
    return "0x" + "".join("{:02x}".format(ord(c)) for c in s)

# transform input / key to hex

msg_hex = function_hex(msg)
print msg_hex

key_hex = function_hex(key)
print key_hex
```